# I want to bind a drop list to an upload

Tags: angular, typescript

I made an upload to the server through the API but I need to send datas with specific title, which should be selected from a dropdown.

In the .html file

```
 <input type="file"  style="display: none" #upLoad (change)= "onFileSelected($event)">
button type="button" (click)="upLoad.click()">PDF Upload</button>
```

Dropdown

`<select [(value)]="selected">`

`<option value="bertrieb">bertrieb</option>`

`<option value="heizen">heizen</option>`

`<option value="all">all</option>`

`</select>`

In the .ts file

onFileSelected(event){

```
this.selectedFile = <File> event.target.files[0];
console.log(event);

const fd = new FormData();
fd.append('files',this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);

this.zeitraumeService.uploadFile(fd).subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
```

})

Comment: Where's the dropdown code?

Comment: <select [(value)]="selected">
  <option value="bertrieb">bertrieb</option>
  <option value="heizen">heizen</option>
  <option value="all">all</option>
</select>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another property to formData

```
fd.append('dropdownDetails', details);
```

Comment: so with my dropdown value I can send it with fd.append('dropdownDetails', selected); I guess

Comment: yes. from the backend find the selected value using `dropdownDetails` key

Comment: I edited with the dropdown code can you please have a check